# Not getting expected output in we scraping R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have written a small program.
Where I **scrape** Google search website and I want all the URL on the Google search web page. But I'm getting character(0) in the O/P. Plz help me.

CODE -

```
library("rvest")
r_h  = read_html("https://www.google.com/search?q=google&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2j69i60l2j69i65.1101j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
d  =  r_h %>% html_nodes(".iUh30") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class is not present in the returned html. You need a different selector strategy and then extract href

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
r_h  = read_html("https://www.google.com/search?q=google&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2j69i60l2j69i65.1101j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
d  =  r_h %>% html_nodes(".jfp3ef > a") %>% html_attr(., "href")

for(i in d){
  res <- str_match_all(i,'(http.*?)&')
  print(res[[1]][,2])
}
```

Comment: Hello sir /maam. How did u get class jfp3ef > a??

Comment: I examined the actual html returned using jsoup and wrote a selector to match what your selector was getting from browser

Comment: Is that the answer you expected?

Comment: Nope.. I'm getting a URL which does not work. Class is wrong I think so.

Comment: try the above please

Comment: Ty. I shall surely try. How did u get class for HTML_nodes??

Comment: It’s the same class. The actual urls just needed extracting from the returned hrefs

Comment: iUh30 does not returns any output. Ur class gives href. How did u get the class?? I searched the entire HTML page of the links/Url of a website. But the class I still get iUh30. How did u get the class? What technique did u use?

Comment: I told you up above ^^ . I looked at the actual html returned in the request - not the html on the page. They are not the same partly due to the fact that javascript runs on the page and alters the DOM where as this does not occur in the xhr request via rvest. So, you should always inspect the actual return html if you don't get the expected result. As mentioned in my top comment I used jsoup to examine the html as well as printing out to file.

Comment: I use CSS selector gadget. How did u get actual HTML ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194257/discussion-between-therii-and-qharr).